# Forward fill NULL values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a table which contains some time-series data.

```
             time              |  bid   |  ask   
-------------------------------+--------+--------
 2018-12-27 01:04:06.978456+00 | 1.7086 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.006461+00 | 1.7087 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.021961+00 |        | 1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:08.882591+00 | 1.7025 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.374118+00 |        | 1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.39018+00  | 1.7087 | 1.7156      
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.793528+00 | 1.7045 | 
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.833545+00 | 1.7083 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.893536+00 |        | 1.7096
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.258062+00 | 1.7045 | 1.7095
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.653573+00 | 1.7046 | 1.7148
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.665564+00 |        | 1.7097
```

I would like to forward-fill over NULL values, so that the result of my query looks like this:

```
             time              |  bid   |  ask   
-------------------------------+--------+--------
 2018-12-27 01:04:06.978456+00 | 1.7086 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.006461+00 | 1.7087 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.021961+00 | 1.7087 | 1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:08.882591+00 | 1.7025 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.374118+00 | 1.7025 | 1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.39018+00  | 1.7087 | 1.7156      
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.793528+00 | 1.7045 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.833545+00 | 1.7083 | 1.7156      
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.893536+00 | 1.7083 | 1.7096
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.258062+00 | 1.7045 | 1.7095
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.653573+00 | 1.7046 | 1.7148
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.665564+00 | 1.7046 | 1.7097
```

How can I achieve this?

I am using postgresql 10, with the timescaledb extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of window functions.  In a subquery, we'll use count to count the rows, excluding nulls, up to the current row, ordered by time, which will let us figure out the separate groups.  From there, we can just use the first_value of that group, if it doesn't already have a value.

```
select t,
       coalesce(bid, first_value(bid) OVER (partition by bid_group ORDER BY t)) as bid_filled,
       coalesce(ask, first_value(ask) OVER (partition by ask_group ORDER BY t)) as ask_filled
FROM (
  select t, ask, bid,
         count(bid) OVER (order by t) as bid_group,
         count(ask) OVER (order by t) as ask_group
  FROM test
) sub;
             t              | bid_filled | ask_filled
----------------------------+------------+------------
 2018-12-27 01:04:06.978456 |     1.7086 |
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.006461 |     1.7087 |
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.021961 |     1.7087 |     1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:08.882591 |     1.7025 |     1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.374118 |     1.7025 |     1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.39018  |     1.7087 |     1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.793528 |     1.7045 |     1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.833545 |     1.7083 |     1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.893536 |     1.7083 |     1.7096
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.258062 |     1.7045 |     1.7095
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.653573 |     1.7046 |     1.7148
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.665564 |     1.7046 |     1.7097
```

Comment: That is really clever!

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple and handy aggregate function for the general purpose of filling gaps:

```
create or replace function last_func(anyelement, anyelement)
returns anyelement language sql immutable strict
as $$
    select $2;
$$;

create aggregate last(anyelement) (
    sfunc = last_func,
    stype = anyelement
);
```

Query:

```
select time, last(bid) over w as bid, last(ask) over w as ask
from my_table
window w as (order by time)
order by time

            time            |  bid   |  ask   
----------------------------+--------+--------
 2018-12-27 01:04:06.978456 | 1.7086 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.006461 | 1.7087 |       
 2018-12-27 01:04:07.021961 | 1.7087 | 1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:08.882591 | 1.7025 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.374118 | 1.7025 | 1.7106
 2018-12-27 01:04:09.39018  | 1.7087 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.793528 | 1.7045 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.833545 | 1.7083 | 1.7156
 2018-12-27 01:04:15.893536 | 1.7083 | 1.7096
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.258062 | 1.7045 | 1.7095
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.653573 | 1.7046 | 1.7148
 2018-12-27 01:04:16.665564 | 1.7046 | 1.7097
(12 rows)
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=474b716738bd4fcef099b0ed56a913bb)