# Fill null values in a table with last non-null value SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to create a table for our data analysis team that contains the "currency exchange rate" ("tasa" in spanish) and I came across a problem. There is this table that contains every rate change made by the store's manager. If he doesn't change the rate, the last date is from when he did. So when I extract those values and pivot the table, I end up with a lot of nulls (mostly from weekends). I would like to return the last non-null value instead. Here is the table structure.

tasas:

| fecha | tasa_v | co_mone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 1.30000 | EUR |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 1.30000 | US$ |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 1.30000 | ZEL |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 1.40000 | ZEL |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 1.40000 | US$ |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 1.40000 | EUR |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.45000 | EUR |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.51500 | EUR |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.45000 | US$ |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.51500 | US$ |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.45000 | ZEL |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.51500 | ZEL |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.65000 | ZEL |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.65000 | US$ |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.65000 | EUR |

Then I join that with a calendar table, and pivot using date and co_mone, as well as AVG() for tasa_v.

```
DECLARE @startdate as date
DECLARE @enddate as date
set @startdate = '20210101'
set @enddate = '20221231'

SELECT  fecha as 'Fecha',[US$],[EUR],[ZEL]
FROM 
(
-- Source is the join between calendar and exchange rates dates
            SELECT F.fecha, T.tasa_v, T.co_mone
            FROM DWSTAGING_GML.dbo.Dim_Fecha F
            left join dbo.tasas as T on cast(T.fecha  as date) = F.fecha
            WHERE F.fecha between @startdate and @enddate
) as SRC
-- pivot the table
PIVOT
(
            AVG(tasa_v) 
            FOR co_mone IN ([US$],[EUR],[ZEL])
) as Pivoted
order by fecha
GO
```

The output:
(modified to show that the columns may have diferent values)

| Fecha | US$ | EUR | ZEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 1.300000 | 1.300000 | 1.300000 |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 1.400000 | 1.400000 | 1.400000 |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.650000 | 1.850000 | 1.650000 |
| 2021-01-09 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

What I'm looking for:

| Fecha | US$ | EUR | ZEL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 1.300000 | 1.300000 | 1.300000 |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 1.400000 | 1.400000 | 1.400000 |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1.400000 | 1.400000 | 1.400000 |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1.650000 | 1.850000 | 1.650000 |
| 2021-01-09 00:00:00 | 1.650000 | 1.850000 | 1.650000 |

I tried the solutions on this [link](https://www.andrewvillazon.com/forward-fill-values-t-sql/) and [this similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107819/forward-fill-null-values-in-multiple-columns)

```
select Fecha,
       coalesce([US$], first_value([US$]) OVER (partition by grupo_US ORDER BY fecha)) as tasa_llenada
FROM (
  select Fecha, [US$]
         count([US$]) OVER (order by fecha) as grupo_US
  FROM (Pivoted_table))
```

but I get the error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
> 'first_value' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Larnu! Thank you for your comment. As you say, updated versions may support what I'm asking. However, it is not my call to update the server. I hope for it to be upgraded anytime soon. 

If it is, would FIRST_VALUE sort it out? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Considering we don't have your attempt using `FIRST_VALUE`, I can't say.

Comment: Can you provide sample data that would be from this table DWSTAGING_GML.dbo.Dim_Fecha - I am assuming this is your "calendar table" - is it simply a column of every date over some range of years?

Comment: @topsail Yes, that is exactly right. It is just a table containing a lot of dates information like year, day, month, etc. Fecha is then the usual__yyyy-mm-dd__ date format.

Comment: @Larnu I just edited the post to implement what I think would be the statement. As I understood, you would use Coalesce to return the first value of the partition created in OVER. Maybe there is a workaround indexing the values?

Comment: its looks like over is not supported in 2008

Comment: does your tasas have any natural way of determining which is the "last" value when there are two on the same date? If they have the same date, they are basically equal by any ordering - so you can only choose one randomly. Can you really know which was first or second?

Comment: Basically, I would really love to see a primary key in that table ... !

Comment: `OVER` is in SQL Server 2008, @topsail . Things like `ROW_NUMBER` have been supported since SQL Server 2000 (iirc). The problem is the minimal support 2008 had for windowing, and the lack of support for analytic functions (which `FIRST_VALUE` is).

Comment: okay good! (I was looking at something about ROWS UNBOUNDED and thought it applied to OVER in general).

Comment: That helps then ... I still think if we OVER the dates it is still non-deterministic which is first or last on a given date, other than perhaps something in the table cluster, unless we can leverage a primary key or something like that). Not ideal - would work though.

Comment: Okay I have thrown out an answer as an opening salvo.

Comment: Gist for creating a sample dataset and testing queries is here: https://gist.github.com/northernocean/cb71083fac2b04dff83a02a4404b0cc8

Comment: @topsail I only care about the avg() on that particular day, as it is only referential. In that regard, I would order it by date.  Let me take a look at your proposal and I'll let you know.

Comment: Fix it in the join on the calendar. First use `LEAD()` to find the next date in `tasas`, then you know the range of calendar dates to join on to. *(Ohhh, 2008... That's not even getting security patches any more! For now, use `OUTER APPLY` to get the following rows date, to mimic `LEAD()`)*

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for filter out the nulls for you !

```
declare @startdate as date;
declare @enddate as date;
set @startdate = '20210101';
set @enddate =   '20210109';

select  fecha as 'Fecha',[US$],[EUR],[ZEL]
from 
(
    -- Source is the join between calendar and exchange rates dates
    select F.fecha, T.tasa_v, T.co_mone
    from #Dim_Fecha F
        left join 
            (select 
                tsub.fecha, tsub.tasa_v, tsub.co_mone, 
                row_number() over (
                    partition by tsub.fecha, tsub.co_mone 
                    order by tsub.fecha ) as id
                from #tasas tsub
                where tsub.tasa_v is not null
                ) T 
        on cast(T.fecha  as date) = F.fecha
        and T.id = 1
    where 
        F.fecha between @startdate and @enddate
) as SRC
-- pivot the table
pivot
(
    avg(tasa_v) 
    for co_mone in ([US$],[EUR],[ZEL])
) as Pivoted
order by Fecha;
```

Actually I think OVER and ROW_NUMBER is superfluous anyway - the main thing is just to filter out nulls right?

So:

```
declare @startdate as date;
declare @enddate as date;
set @startdate = '20210101';
set @enddate =   '20210109';

select  fecha as 'Fecha',[US$],[EUR],[ZEL]
from 
(
    -- Source is the join between calendar and exchange rates dates
    select F.fecha, T.tasa_v, T.co_mone
    from #Dim_Fecha F
        left join 
            (select 
                tsub.fecha, tsub.tasa_v, tsub.co_mone 
                from #tasas tsub
                where tsub.tasa_v is not null
                ) T 
        on cast(T.fecha  as date) = F.fecha
    where 
        F.fecha between @startdate and @enddate
) as SRC
-- pivot the table
pivot
(
    avg(tasa_v) 
    for co_mone in ([US$],[EUR],[ZEL])
) as Pivoted
order by Fecha;
```

Comment: Saddly it did not work. The null values are from the left join with Calendar. That of course is intentional as I need all the Calendar and not just the dates on which there was a rate change.

So just filtering .tasa_v is not null won't solve it.

Comment: My solution is a left join (all dates from calendar table). Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, but that is already something that I do. What I saw is that you specified __is not null__ in the subquery's where clause. But that is irrelevant to the problem itself, because the null value doesn't come from that table, but rather the join between that table and the Calendar. After the join I have to fill the null values with the last non-null.

Comment: I just realized that I put null values in the first table, giving the impresion that the null's were from Tasas and not the join itself. Sorry for that, it's fixed now. @topsail

Comment: Ah okay. Yes, that was what I thought. You're solution ("what I'm looking for" also has nulls). Are you okay with nulls in "some cases"?